# How to set ggplot2 fill color to aggregate statistic?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, aggregate, data-visualization

I want to set the fill colors of bars in a ggplot2 bar chart of one variable according to an aggregate stat of another variable.

For instance, using the house price regression data from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data) I might want to use color to visualize the mean sale price of homes in each category in a bar chart.

```
ggplot(
  data = df,
  mapping = aes(x = OverallCond, fill = mean(SalePrice))
) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

This is not the graph I'm looking for. Each bar should be a color that represents the average sale price within that category.

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate the mean values by category first and then plot them using `geom_col()`. Here is an example using `mtcars` dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(carb = factor(carb)) %>% 
  summarise(m = mean(disp)) %>% 
  ungroup()

ggplot(
  data = d,
  mapping = aes(x = carb, y = m, fill = carb)
) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're putting the aggregate on the y axis, rather than encoding it in the color. Color in your plot is encoding carb and is redundant to the x axis. I want to maintain the y axis (as the count in my example), and encode the aggregate (mean(SalePrice) in my example) in the color. I suppose you could create a new factor that represents the means of the carb groups.